# Why 54 + 400 = 453?

Tags: c++

I wanted to convert a string to an integer, and I find the "454" was converted to 453.

I have defined a function which can convert an integer-string to an integer. But when I tested it, I found the "454" was converted to 453. I tried another number 565, and it is correct.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int strtonum(string num){
    int i = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int result=0;
    for(i = num.length()-1; i>=0; i--,n++){
        if(num[i] == '-'){
        result-=2*result;
        break;
        }
        cout<<result<<" + "<<(num[i] - '0')*pow(10,n);
        result += (num[i] - '0')*pow(10,n);
        cout<<" = "<<result<<endl;
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    string x;
    cin>>x;
    cout<<strtonum(x)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

## Result

```
454
0 + 4 = 4
4 + 50 = 54
54 + 400 = 453
453

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 2.763 s
Press any key to continue.  

565
0 + 5 = 5
5 + 60 = 65
65 + 500 = 565
565

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 3.314 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: [No repro!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f157cb534a98acf7)

Comment: I do not have your behavior for 454, all is ok for me. Why `result-=2*result;` rather than just `result = -result;` ? to increase the chance of an overflow ?

Comment: @bruno Yes that is total execution time from the surrounding environment (VS)

Comment: This screams rounding error but everything should be whole numbers (which are generally not too prone to that) so um is this your real [mcve]?

Comment: May be something to do with double accuracy: [`pow(10,n)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) relies on floating point implementations, which might get unexpected result when hard casted to an `int` value.

Comment: [No repro on clang either](https://godbolt.org/z/0D2zR_) (unsurprisingly) - but really just spreading awareness of godbolt.org code execution support :D

Comment: It may be a rounding error with `std::pow` which operators on `double`s.

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code statement by statement. And split up larger expressions into smaller that are easier to check the result of (for example for `result += (num[i] - '0')*pow(10,n)` you could to `int tmp1 = num[i]; in tmp2 = tmp1 - '0'; int tmp3 = pow(10, n); int tmp4 = tmp2 * tmp3; result += tmp4;`) That makes it easier to see exactly what happens and where the rounding errors could be.

Comment: As for the sting-to-integer conversion itself, it can be done without any `pow` function call and risking floating-point rounding problems. Initialize the result to zero, then in a loop multiply the result by `10` and add a digit from the string (starting from the first digit, i.e. the first element of the string). After the loop is done then the result is the number in integer form. So each iteration all you do is one multiplication, one subtraction (to get the digit in integer form) and one addition.

Comment: Which compiler on which platform ? There should be no issue with this parameter. The comments and answers about floating point error are not accurate. The 53 bits of mantissa are more than enough for exact integral computation in your case.

Comment: @Michale Doubez But when I define the result as a floating-point number, it`s correct.

Comment: @MichaelDoubez Evidence to the contrary, for whatever reason.

Comment: @Lightness were you able to reproduce the issue ? There is no evidence unless you have a basis for it. It could also be a compiler bug. That s why I ask the platform and the compiler ... The OP didn't provide it.

Comment: @MichaelDoubez Code::Blocks-17.12 with GNU GCC Compiler on Windows10.

Comment: @MichaelDoubez So you're calling the OP a liar?

Comment: Only that the reason advanced (namely float precision) is the wrong answer and there must be another reason for what is observed. @PT.lang CodeBlocks is the IDE, what version/package of gcc ?

Comment: OK, I assumed you were using the old TDM 5.1. I was able to reproduce the issue. This is due to a poor implementation of `std::pow()` that introduce some rounding errors. More modern c++ compiler don't have the issue.

Comment: This must be something related to the TDM 5.1 32bits on windows because I couldn't reproduce it with the same version on other architectures. Try it on https://wandbox.org/

Answer (score 1):

Your approach involves floating-point computations through your use of the `std::pow` function.

As you may know, floating-point computations can introduce error. I'm a little surprised to see that here with good wholesome whole numbers, but still you're not dealing with it at all before truncating back to `int`.

I suggest a different, integer-only manner of raising to a power of ten (perhaps a nice loop!).

Also, as bruno pointed out, this:

```
result-=2*result;
```

is overflow-prone and unnecessary when you can just do this instead:

```
result = -result;
```

or:

```
result *= -1;
```

Comment: In my mind a 54.0 [would have been stored](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f924c44ca1e68ee8) as, well [the binary equiv of] 54e0 rather than as 5.4e1 but hey what do I know!

Comment: On 64bits floating point number, powers of 10 have exact representation up to 10^22. You don't need a loop, a cast is enough.

Comment: I try to define the result as floating-point number, and the result is correct. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @MichaelDoubez That's what I would have thought, but then this question..

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach to this is to accumulate values with multiplication by 10:

```
int convert(std::string text) {
    bool negative = false;
    int cur = 0;
    if (text[cur] == '-') {
        negative = true;
        ++cur;
    }
    int value = 0;
    while (cur < text.length()) {
        value *= 10;
        value += text[cur++] - '0';
    }
    if (negative)
        value = -value;
    return value;
}
```

Note: this code has not been tested. It might contain errors.

Comment: I do not expect to be able to do this. Thanks for your advice.